# Controller returning InputStreamResource or UrlResource doesn't work if annotated with @BasePathAwareController but works with @RestController

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have a controller that is returning a `UrlResource` or `InputStreamResource`. This controller is able to return the file contents when it is annotated with `@RestController` but not with `@BasePathAwareController`.

```
// @RestController
@BasePathAwareController
public class FileController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileController.class);

    @Autowired
    private FileStorageService fileStorageService;

    @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{fileName:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Load file as Resource
        Resource resource = fileStorageService.loadFileAsResource(fileName);

        // Try to determine file's content type
        String contentType = null;
        try {
            contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info("Could not determine file type.");
        }

        // Fallback to the default content type if type could not be determined
        if(contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
    }

}
```

This code sample is taken from https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example and one can reproduce this using the repository and switching the `@RestController` with `@BasePathAwareController`. Also, `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` needs to be added as a dependency.

My question is how can I get this to work using `@BasePathAwareController`. I want to use it since I want the controller to be configured under the `basePath` I am setting in my `application.properties`.